# Ajax Post to guestEntries/saveEntries from another domain

Tags: ajax, guest-entries, apache, post, plugin-guestentries

I have a separate Craft install that I am using to communicate to a few different sites. I have a front-end form on another one of these sites (a React.js app) that is looking to post back to this initial Craft install.

My form looks pretty standard:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="3"/>

    <input id="name" type="text" name="fields[name]" required />
    <input id="userEmail" type="email" name="fields[userEmail]" required/>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

`handleSubmit()` also looks exactly the same as the docs for [ContactFormEntries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#ajax-form-submissions):

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $('form').serialize();

    $.post(config.default.apiUrl, data, function(response){
        if(response.success){
            $('body').addClass('success');
        }
        else{
            alert('Sorry, there was an error with your submission. Please validate your submission or try again later.');
        }
    });
}
```

*where `config.default.apiUrl` = the root url for my Craft app.*

My data goes through as a POST request (`302 Found`) followed by an immediate GET request of `'/'` (`200 OK`) where `response` is the markup from the root of the Craft install.

The kicker is that the data is saved in the database correctly, but the `response` (and the subsequent GET request) isn't really what I'm looking for. I'd love for it return with a proper `json` response. I've attempted to include a redirect parameter, but the result is the same.

Is there something I am missing in my ajax request that would throw this off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Turns out this was an issue with my apache config on the Craft instance.

**Explanation**: I did a little digging around the GuestEntriesController.php file and noticed that Craft was not picking up that my POST was coming from an ajax request. After looking into that more I manually added the ajax header to my post request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: config.default.apiUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
}).done(function(){ ... });
```

This got me a little closer, but now on request I was getting hit with this error:

> Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

That led me to a simple Google search that had the answer in [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work).

In my Craft App's `.htaccess` file I added in the following 2 headers:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
```

Now my POST request from another server fires fine, and Craft returns with a successful `json` response.